# OS X mavericks - Stop applications using the /Library folder

Tags: macos, mac

I want to keep the separation between the base system and what I have installed very clear and after reading a bit on the web I saw the recommended way is to install applications under ~/Applications. I don't want applications I've installed to only be usable by one account so I figured I would install user wide applications under a shared directory in /Users/Shared/Applications.

Assuming this is a good way of approaching the problem my worry is that I do not want applications to store data in /Library but rather store under /Users/Shared/Library. In other words I want applications running out of /Users/Shared/Applications to treat /Users/Shared as their root directory.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: No. Also, nobody expects applications to be in `/Users/Shared/Applications`. And `/Users/Shared` isn't a standard location FWIW. That said, you can organize most of your own applications arbitrarily, copy them e.g. to `/Applications/Dan`. Most apps will write to `~/Library` (and a few to `/Library`) though.

Comment: Ok well lets say I let my child on my macbook and I don't want them to play violent games I've installed but I do want to let my wife play it, we all have different user accounts. What I'm thinking is a separate applications folder that I can only allow a certain group (me and my wife) to access. This is a practical use of what I hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can still install the Applications into `/Applications` (where most installers install them anyway) and use ParentalControl to limit access for your child only to specific applications.

That way you do not need to interfere with default locations (Some applications even expect themselves to be unter `/Applications` and will refuse to run if installed in other places) and you can still restrict access to those applications.